# Align items in navbar with searchbar

Tags: html, css

I'm learning css and I want a custom navbar where I want to do something like this:

[image]

So I create the navbar item and inside it each element separately. Problem is my social media icons not in the same line as the search bar.

There is my code example of what am I doing

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#product-overview {
    background-color: #ff1b68;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }

#product-overview h1{
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width:100%;
background: #2ddf5c;
padding:8px 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #0e4f1f;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}

.main-nav__items{
display: flex;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav__social{
    display:block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a></div><nav class="main-nav">
                    <div><input type="text" placeholder="search" class="main-nav__searchbar"></div>
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="social-media__icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="social-media__icons/instagram-bosquejado.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Someone can tell me what is wrong with spaces inside my box? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: flex;` to the `.main-nav` to make the direct children of the `.main-nav` (which are the `div` that contains the search bar and the `ul` that contains the social media icons) aligned in the same line

try this code:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#product-overview {
    background-color: #ff1b68;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }

#product-overview h1{
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width:100%;
background: #2ddf5c;
padding: 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #0e4f1f;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav__searchbar{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav__items{
display: flex;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav__social{
    display:block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a>
                </div>
                
                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <div class="main-nav__searchbar_container">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="main-nav__searchbar">
                    </div>
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="social-media__icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <img class="main-nav__social" src="social-media__icons/instagram-bosquejado.svg" alt="facebook">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: Nice! it works, as you can see in design the width of searchbar is more larger but it is with `width: 100%`, to achieve that I need to increase that value I.E 200% then work in media queryies to do responsive design?

Comment: I updated the code, I added `.main-nav__searchbar_container` with `display:flex` and `width:100%` and set `width:100%` to `.main-nav`, also I added some paddings to make it look good